# How do I switch between cameras?

Tags: camera

I have two render camera objects in the scene, about to be three, I'd like to know how to switch between them as when I hit zero, it only enters the view of my frontal camera(the first one I placed.) is it possible to switch between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut for that!
You press ctrl+numpad 0 to set the main camera to the the one you selected! You can also change it in the properties pannel

Comment: Thank you! I was almost mad last night when I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Change the main camera for your scene in properties panel:

[image]